# Button group width causing horizontal alignment problems in column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, alignment

I've got the following button group that starts out vertical and then switches to horizontal as the screen compresses.

It works, but the enclosing div gains extra horizontal space when the screen size is large, as though it's reactively growing wider. This is a problem because I'm trying to align the button group's column with the column to the right, and the extra width makes it impossible. The `col-sm-1` does not seem to gain this extra space--is this just how bootstrap works? Also, is there any way to say "make each button right-aligned to the column border"?

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-down"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** **Updated** [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hamiltont/pyj2zwvj/5/)

It's tough to see what I mean, so here's an image. I've made the fiddle full screen and used Chrome's devtools to highlight the button group. You can see that extra width has been added. Note that I'm not highlighting the column (where I would expect extra width), but the button group inside the column

[image: button has too much width]

Comment: CAn you fiddle your code please . Thanks

Comment: Added, plus and image showing the exact problem

Comment: Incorrect fiddle link.

Comment: fixed, thanks for catching

Comment: Not following this. The column grid system is fluid, so it's going to gain and lose depending on the viewport. The width of single column is 1/12 of 100%, so about 8. something %. There is 30 px between each column as the gutter (that's 15px L & R padding on the columns). If you want to stick something that aligns right, wrap the button-group in something and float it to the right at the min-width you want. If you want to smash it against the other column, then remove the right-padding on that column ONLY on the min width then there will be 15 px between, if you want to have no gutter...

Comment: remove the left padding on the column after ONLY at that min-width

Comment: Christina, thanks for looking. Note that the column is just wrapping the button groups width. Its the button group inside the column that is changing width. This means i cant align anything to right side of the button group because its too wide. I cant align the right side of the column because the button group's extra right width will cause odd spacing. Its late here though so perhaps  just nit thinking clearly, ill check if someone has proved me wrong in the morning ;-)

Comment: Don't know when/how you switch it to horizontal from vertical, because the `col-sm-1` will probably never let you go full horizontal. But why don't you try using `btn-group-vertical` when you know the buttons should look like that?

Comment: @azeós - did you check the fiddle? This flows horizontal to vertical perfectly, exactly as is expected. If you use a group vertical then your mobile clients will be forced to see a vertical list when the columns wrap - not good. If you use a normal button group it stacks vertical when it's low on width and goes horizontal when it's not (as shown in the bootstrap examples). Only issue is the mis-rounded corners but that's an easy thing to fix.

Comment: All, I've updated my image and the fiddle to show content to the right of the button group. All I'm trying to do is align the *content* inside these two columns! Not sure why this seems so tough :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! It was the button group making things tricky - this adds a `float: left` to each button to make them a group, so the correct fix seems to be adding the `pull-right` class to each button in the group.

This works as desired, and once I remove the padding the buttons will stay perfectly bumped against the right side of their column. [Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/hamiltont/pyj2zwvj/5/)

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-down"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-out"></span></button>
  <button
    class="btn btn-default pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red">
    <p>Here is content I would like the buttons to touch</p>
</div>
```